# Position the vehicle in the direction of travel on race track

Tags: python

I wrote algorithm to calculate racing line and work fine for me. I have a problem with the car facing forward.
I use the function to determine the position of the car:

```
car_p = getSplinePoint()
```

I get x and y cords.

I can also use function

```
car_g = getSplineSlope()
```

to get slope of the track.

I transform my image by:

```
self.image = self.src_image
self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.src_image, ANGLE)
```

I start my car with angle 0.
I don't know how to calculate the angle at which the car should be turned so that it is directed in the appropriate direction.

[image]

Could you tell my how I should calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I don't use pygame so there might be a better solution but I've come up with this method:
Keep track of a vector (which we'l call v) and make it point to the direction to which the car's facing. Then, make another vector (u) which will go from the car to the next waypoint.
Then use this formula to get the cosine of the angle between both vectors:

```
cosθ = (v·u)/(||v||·||u||)
||v|| is the length of the vector v.
```

After you've obtained the cosine you can simply get the angle by calculating the arcosine of the result. It's a bit messy, but if pygame doesn't have any command to do this automatically then al least it will do the job.